# WSO2 API Manager: Migration script for Oracle 1.6.0 -> 1.7.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

There is no migration script for an Oracle database if you run on 1.6.0 and wanna use 1.7.0. I created an [Jira issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2524) on this. I have created a solution.

Based on the migration script of mysql.sql and the install script of Oracle, I merged those two together.

The result is my migration script for Oracle, I hope it contains all the steps.

```
    ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS DROP COLUMN LOGIN_PAGE_URL
/
ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS DROP COLUMN ERROR_PAGE_URL
/
ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS DROP COLUMN CONSENT_PAGE_URL
/
/*
DROP INDEX IDX_AT_CK_AU
/
DROP SEQUENCE IDP_SEQUENCE
/
DROP SEQUENCE IDP_ROLE_MAPPINGS_SEQUENCE
/
DROP SEQUENCE IDP_ROLES_SEQUENCE
/
ALTER TABLE UM_TENANT_IDP_ROLE_MAPPINGS DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE
/
ALTER TABLE UM_TENANT_IDP_ROLES DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE
/
ALTER TABLE IDP_BASE_TABLE DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE
/
ALTER TABLE UM_TENANT_IDP DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE
/
DROP TABLE UM_TENANT_IDP_ROLE_MAPPINGS CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
/
DROP TABLE UM_TENANT_IDP_ROLES CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
/
DROP TABLE UM_TENANT_IDP CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
/
DROP TABLE IDP_BASE_TABLE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
/
*/
ALTER TABLE AM_API_URL_MAPPING ADD (MEDIATION_SCRIPT BLOB DEFAULT NULL)
/
CREATE TABLE IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE (
            SCOPE_ID INTEGER,
            SCOPE_KEY VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
            NAME VARCHAR2 (255) NULL,
            DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2 (512) NULL,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        ROLES VARCHAR2 (500) NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (SCOPE_ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_SEQUENCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_TRIGGER
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                SELECT IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_SEQUENCE.nextval INTO :NEW.SCOPE_ID FROM dual;
            END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDN_OAUTH2_RESOURCE_SCOPE (
            RESOURCE_PATH VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
            SCOPE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (RESOURCE_PATH),
            FOREIGN KEY (SCOPE_ID) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE (SCOPE_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
/
CREATE TABLE IDN_SCIM_GROUP (
        ID INTEGER,
        TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ROLE_NAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
            ATTR_NAME VARCHAR2(1024) NOT NULL,
        ATTR_VALUE VARCHAR2(1024),
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDN_SCIM_GROUP_SEQUENCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDN_SCIM_GROUP_TRIGGER
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDN_SCIM_GROUP
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                SELECT IDN_SCIM_GROUP_SEQUENCE.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
            END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDN_SCIM_PROVIDER (
            CONSUMER_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            PROVIDER_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            USER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            USER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            USER_URL VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
        GROUP_URL VARCHAR(1024),
        BULK_URL VARCHAR(1024),
            PRIMARY KEY (CONSUMER_ID,PROVIDER_ID))
/
CREATE TABLE IDN_OPENID_REMEMBER_ME (
            USER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
            COOKIE_VALUE VARCHAR(1024),
            CREATED_TIME TIMESTAMP,
            PRIMARY KEY (USER_NAME, TENANT_ID))
/
CREATE TABLE IDN_OPENID_ASSOCIATIONS (
        HANDLE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            ASSOC_TYPE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            EXPIRE_IN TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
            MAC_KEY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            ASSOC_STORE VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'SHARED',
            PRIMARY KEY (HANDLE))
/
CREATE TABLE IDN_STS_STORE (
            ID INTEGER,
            TOKEN_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            TOKEN_CONTENT BLOB NOT NULL,
            CREATE_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
            EXPIRE_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
            STATE INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDN_STS_STORE_SEQUENCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDN_STS_STORE_TRIGGER
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDN_STS_STORE
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                SELECT IDN_STS_STORE_SEQUENCE.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
            END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA (
            TENANT_ID INTEGER DEFAULT -1234,
            USER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            DATA_KEY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            DATA_VALUE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (TENANT_ID, USER_NAME, DATA_KEY))
/
CREATE TABLE IDN_IDENTITY_META_DATA (
            USER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER DEFAULT -1234,
            METADATA_TYPE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            METADATA VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            VALID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (TENANT_ID, USER_NAME, METADATA_TYPE,METADATA))
/
-- End of IDN Tables --


-- Start of IDN-APPLICATION-MGT Tables--

CREATE TABLE SP_APP (
            ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        APP_NAME VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ,
        USER_STORE VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
            USERNAME VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ,
            DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (1024),
        ROLE_CLAIM VARCHAR (512),
            AUTH_TYPE VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
        PROVISIONING_USERSTORE_DOMAIN VARCHAR (512),
        IS_LOCAL_CLAIM_DIALECT CHAR(1) DEFAULT '1',
            IS_SEND_LOCAL_SUBJECT_ID CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            IS_SEND_AUTH_LIST_OF_IDPS CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            SUBJECT_CLAIM_URI VARCHAR (512),
            IS_SAAS_APP CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE SP_APP_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SP_APP_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON SP_APP
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT SP_APP_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX APPLICATION_NAME_CONSTRAINT ON SP_APP(APP_NAME, TENANT_ID)
/
ALTER TABLE SP_APP ADD CONSTRAINT APPLICATION_NAME_CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (APP_NAME, TENANT_ID) USING INDEX APPLICATION_NAME_CONSTRAINT
/
CREATE TABLE SP_INBOUND_AUTH (
            ID INTEGER,
        TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        INBOUND_AUTH_KEY VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
            INBOUND_AUTH_TYPE VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
            PROP_NAME VARCHAR (255),
            PROP_VALUE VARCHAR (1024) ,
        APP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE SP_INBOUND_AUTH_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SP_INBOUND_AUTH_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON SP_INBOUND_AUTH
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT SP_INBOUND_AUTH_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
ALTER TABLE SP_INBOUND_AUTH ADD CONSTRAINT APPLICATION_ID_CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (APP_ID) REFERENCES SP_APP (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
CREATE TABLE SP_AUTH_STEP (
            ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        STEP_ORDER INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
            APP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
            IS_SUBJECT_STEP CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            IS_ATTRIBUTE_STEP CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE SP_AUTH_STEP_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SP_AUTH_STEP_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON SP_AUTH_STEP
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT SP_AUTH_STEP_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
ALTER TABLE SP_AUTH_STEP ADD CONSTRAINT APPLICATION_ID_CONSTRAINT_STEP FOREIGN KEY (APP_ID) REFERENCES SP_APP (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
CREATE TABLE SP_FEDERATED_IDP (
            ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            AUTHENTICATOR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID, AUTHENTICATOR_ID))
/
ALTER TABLE SP_FEDERATED_IDP ADD CONSTRAINT STEP_ID_CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES SP_AUTH_STEP (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
CREATE TABLE SP_CLAIM_MAPPING (
        ID INTEGER,
        TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        IDP_CLAIM VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL ,
            SP_CLAIM VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL ,
        APP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        IS_REQUESTED VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '0',
            DEFAULT_VALUE VARCHAR(255),
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE SP_CLAIM_MAPPING_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SP_CLAIM_MAPPING_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON SP_CLAIM_MAPPING
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT SP_CLAIM_MAPPING_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
ALTER TABLE SP_CLAIM_MAPPING ADD CONSTRAINT CLAIMID_APPID_CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (APP_ID) REFERENCES SP_APP (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
CREATE TABLE SP_ROLE_MAPPING (
        ID INTEGER,
        TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        IDP_ROLE VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ,
            SP_ROLE VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ,
        APP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE SP_ROLE_MAPPING_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SP_ROLE_MAPPING_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON SP_ROLE_MAPPING
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT SP_ROLE_MAPPING_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
ALTER TABLE SP_ROLE_MAPPING ADD CONSTRAINT ROLEID_APPID_CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (APP_ID) REFERENCES SP_APP (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
CREATE TABLE SP_REQ_PATH_AUTHENTICATOR (
        ID INTEGER,
        TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        AUTHENTICATOR_NAME VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ,
        APP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE SP_REQ_PATH_AUTH_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SP_REQ_PATH_AUTH_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON SP_REQ_PATH_AUTHENTICATOR
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT SP_REQ_PATH_AUTH_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
ALTER TABLE SP_REQ_PATH_AUTHENTICATOR ADD CONSTRAINT REQ_AUTH_APPID_CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (APP_ID) REFERENCES SP_APP (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
CREATE TABLE SP_PROVISIONING_CONNECTOR (
        ID INTEGER,
        TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            IDP_NAME VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ,
        CONNECTOR_NAME VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ,
        APP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        IS_JIT_ENABLED CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            BLOCKING CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE SP_PROV_CONNECTOR_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SP_PROV_CONNECTOR_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON SP_PROVISIONING_CONNECTOR
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT SP_PROV_CONNECTOR_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
ALTER TABLE SP_PROVISIONING_CONNECTOR ADD CONSTRAINT PRO_CONNECTOR_APPID_CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (APP_ID) REFERENCES SP_APP (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
CREATE TABLE IDP (
            ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            NAME VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
            IS_ENABLED CHAR(1) DEFAULT '1',
            IS_PRIMARY CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            HOME_REALM_ID VARCHAR(254),
            IMAGE BLOB,
            CERTIFICATE BLOB,
            ALIAS VARCHAR(254),
            INBOUND_PROV_ENABLED CHAR (1) DEFAULT '0',
            INBOUND_PROV_USER_STORE_ID VARCHAR(254),
            USER_CLAIM_URI VARCHAR(254),
            ROLE_CLAIM_URI VARCHAR(254),
            DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (1024),
            DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATOR_NAME VARCHAR(254),
            DEFAULT_PRO_CONNECTOR_NAME VARCHAR(254),
            PROVISIONING_ROLE VARCHAR(128),
            IS_FEDERATION_HUB CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            IS_LOCAL_CLAIM_DIALECT CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            DISPLAY_NAME VARCHAR(254),
            UNIQUE (TENANT_ID, NAME))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
INSERT INTO IDP (TENANT_ID, NAME, HOME_REALM_ID) VALUES (-1234, 'LOCAL', 'localhost')
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_ROLE (
            ID INTEGER,
            IDP_ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            ROLE VARCHAR(254),
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (IDP_ID, ROLE),
            FOREIGN KEY (IDP_ID) REFERENCES IDP(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_ROLE_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_ROLE_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_ROLE
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_ROLE_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_ROLE_MAPPING (
            ID INTEGER,
            IDP_ROLE_ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            USER_STORE_ID VARCHAR (253),
            LOCAL_ROLE VARCHAR(253),
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (IDP_ROLE_ID, TENANT_ID, USER_STORE_ID, LOCAL_ROLE),
            FOREIGN KEY (IDP_ROLE_ID) REFERENCES IDP_ROLE(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_ROLE_MAPPING_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_ROLE_MAPPING_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_ROLE_MAPPING
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_ROLE_MAPPING_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_CLAIM (
            ID INTEGER,
            IDP_ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            CLAIM VARCHAR(254),
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (IDP_ID, CLAIM),
            FOREIGN KEY (IDP_ID) REFERENCES IDP(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_CLAIM_MAPPING (
            ID INTEGER,
            IDP_CLAIM_ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            LOCAL_CLAIM VARCHAR(253),
            DEFAULT_VALUE VARCHAR(255),
            IS_REQUESTED VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (IDP_CLAIM_ID, TENANT_ID, LOCAL_CLAIM),
            FOREIGN KEY (IDP_CLAIM_ID) REFERENCES IDP_CLAIM(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_CLAIM_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_CLAIM_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_CLAIM
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_CLAIM_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_CLAIM_MAPPING_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_CLAIM_MAPPING_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_CLAIM_MAPPING
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_CLAIM_MAPPING_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_AUTHENTICATOR (
            ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            IDP_ID INTEGER,
            NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            IS_ENABLED CHAR (1) DEFAULT '1',
            DISPLAY_NAME VARCHAR(255),
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (TENANT_ID, IDP_ID, NAME),
            FOREIGN KEY (IDP_ID) REFERENCES IDP(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_AUTHENTICATOR_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_AUTHENTICATOR_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_AUTHENTICATOR
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_AUTHENTICATOR_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
INSERT INTO IDP_AUTHENTICATOR (TENANT_ID, IDP_ID, NAME) VALUES (-1234, 1, 'saml2sso')
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_AUTHENTICATOR_PROPERTY (
            ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            AUTHENTICATOR_ID INTEGER,
            PROPERTY_KEY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            PROPERTY_VALUE VARCHAR(2047),
            IS_SECRET CHAR (1) DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (TENANT_ID, AUTHENTICATOR_ID, PROPERTY_KEY),
            FOREIGN KEY (AUTHENTICATOR_ID) REFERENCES IDP_AUTHENTICATOR(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_AUTHENTICATOR_PROP_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_AUTHENTICATOR_PROP_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_AUTHENTICATOR_PROPERTY
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_AUTHENTICATOR_PROP_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_PROVISIONING_CONFIG (
            ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            IDP_ID INTEGER,
            PROVISIONING_CONNECTOR_TYPE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            IS_ENABLED CHAR (1) DEFAULT '0',
            IS_BLOCKING CHAR (1) DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (TENANT_ID, IDP_ID, PROVISIONING_CONNECTOR_TYPE),
            FOREIGN KEY (IDP_ID) REFERENCES IDP(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_PROVISIONING_CONFIG_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_PROVISIONING_CONFIG_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_PROVISIONING_CONFIG
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_PROVISIONING_CONFIG_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_PROV_CONFIG_PROPERTY (
            ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID INTEGER,
            PROPERTY_KEY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            PROPERTY_VALUE VARCHAR(2048),
            PROPERTY_BLOB_VALUE BLOB,
            PROPERTY_TYPE CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
            IS_SECRET CHAR (1) DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (TENANT_ID, PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID, PROPERTY_KEY),
            FOREIGN KEY (PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID) REFERENCES IDP_PROVISIONING_CONFIG(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_PROV_CONFIG_PROP_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_PROV_CONFIG_PROP_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_PROV_CONFIG_PROPERTY
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_PROV_CONFIG_PROP_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY (
            ID INTEGER,
            PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID INTEGER,
            ENTITY_TYPE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            ENTITY_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            ENTITY_VALUE VARCHAR(255),
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (ENTITY_TYPE, TENANT_ID, ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE, ENTITY_NAME),
            UNIQUE (PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, ENTITY_VALUE),
            FOREIGN KEY (PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID) REFERENCES IDP_PROVISIONING_CONFIG(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_PROV_ENTITY_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_PROV_ENTITY_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_PROV_ENTITY_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/
CREATE TABLE IDP_LOCAL_CLAIM (
            ID INTEGER,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER,
            IDP_ID INTEGER,
            CLAIM_URI VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            DEFAULT_VALUE VARCHAR(255),
            IS_REQUESTED VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (TENANT_ID, IDP_ID, CLAIM_URI),
            FOREIGN KEY (IDP_ID) REFERENCES IDP(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE IDP_LOCAL_CLAIM_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDP_LOCAL_CLAIM_TRIG
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON IDP_LOCAL_CLAIM
            REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
            FOR EACH ROW
               BEGIN
                   SELECT IDP_LOCAL_CLAIM_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
               END;
/

-- End of IDN-APPLICATION-MGT Tables--

ALTER TABLE AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE
/
ALTER TABLE AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING ADD (STATE  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) DEFAULT 'COMPLETED' NOT NULL)
/
ALTER TABLE AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING ADD PRIMARY KEY (APPLICATION_ID, KEY_TYPE)
/
CREATE TABLE AM_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION (
            REG_ID INTEGER ,
            SUBSCRIBER_ID INTEGER,
            WF_REF VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
            APP_ID INTEGER,
            TOKEN_TYPE VARCHAR2(30),
            ALLOWED_DOMAINS VARCHAR2(256),
            VALIDITY_PERIOD NUMBER(19),
            UNIQUE (SUBSCRIBER_ID,APP_ID,TOKEN_TYPE),
            FOREIGN KEY(SUBSCRIBER_ID) REFERENCES AM_SUBSCRIBER(SUBSCRIBER_ID),
            FOREIGN KEY(APP_ID) REFERENCES AM_APPLICATION(APPLICATION_ID),
            PRIMARY KEY (REG_ID)
)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE AM_APP_REGISTRATION_SEQUENCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AM_APP_REGISTRATION_TRIGGER
      BEFORE INSERT
  ON AM_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT AM_APP_REGISTRATION_SEQUENCE.nextval INTO :NEW.REG_ID FROM dual;
  END;
/
CREATE TABLE AM_API_SCOPES (
            API_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
            SCOPE_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (API_ID) REFERENCES AM_API (API_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
            FOREIGN KEY (SCOPE_ID) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE (SCOPE_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
/
CREATE TABLE AM_API_DEFAULT_VERSION (
            DEFAULT_VERSION_ID NUMBER, 
            API_NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL ,
            API_PROVIDER VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL , 
            DEFAULT_API_VERSION VARCHAR(30) , 
            PUBLISHED_DEFAULT_API_VERSION VARCHAR(30) ,
            PRIMARY KEY (DEFAULT_VERSION_ID)
)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE AM_API_DEFAULT_VERSION_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AM_API_DEFAULT_VERSION_TRG
                    BEFORE INSERT
                    ON AM_API_DEFAULT_VERSION
                    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
                    FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN
                    SELECT AM_API_DEFAULT_VERSION_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.DEFAULT_VERSION_ID FROM dual;
                    END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DROP_ALL_SCHEMA_OBJECTS RETURN NUMBER AS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
cursor c_get_objects is
  select object_type,'"'||object_name||'"'||decode(object_type,'TABLE' ,' cascade constraints',null) obj_name
  from user_objects
  where object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW','PACKAGE','SEQUENCE','SYNONYM', 'MATERIALIZED VIEW')
  order by object_type;
cursor c_get_objects_type is
  select object_type, '"'||object_name||'"' obj_name
  from user_objects
  where object_type in ('TYPE');
BEGIN
  begin
  for object_rec in c_get_objects loop
  execute immediate ('drop '||object_rec.object_type||' ' ||object_rec.obj_name);
  end loop;
  for object_rec in c_get_objects_type loop
  begin
  execute immediate ('drop '||object_rec.object_type||' ' ||object_rec.obj_name);
  end;
  end loop;
  end;
  RETURN 0;
END DROP_ALL_SCHEMA_OBJECTS;
/
ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN MODIFY(TOKEN_SCOPE VARCHAR2(2048 BYTE))
/
DECLARE 
statement VARCHAR2(2000);
constr_name VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME INTO constr_name FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE table_name  = 'IDN_OAUTH1A_ACCESS_TOKEN' AND column_name = 'CONSUMER_KEY';
   statement := 'ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH1A_ACCESS_TOKEN DROP CONSTRAINT '|| constr_name;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(statement); 
END;
/
ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH1A_ACCESS_TOKEN ADD FOREIGN KEY (CONSUMER_KEY) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS (CONSUMER_KEY) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
DECLARE 
statement VARCHAR2(2000);
constr_name VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME INTO constr_name FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE table_name  = 'IDN_OAUTH1A_REQUEST_TOKEN' AND column_name = 'CONSUMER_KEY';
   statement := 'ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH1A_REQUEST_TOKEN DROP CONSTRAINT '|| constr_name;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(statement); 
END;
/
ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH1A_REQUEST_TOKEN ADD FOREIGN KEY (CONSUMER_KEY) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS (CONSUMER_KEY) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
DECLARE 
statement VARCHAR2(2000);
constr_name VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME INTO constr_name FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE table_name  = 'IDN_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE' AND column_name = 'CONSUMER_KEY';
   statement := 'ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE DROP CONSTRAINT '|| constr_name;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(statement); 
END;
/
ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE ADD FOREIGN KEY (CONSUMER_KEY) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS (CONSUMER_KEY) ON DELETE CASCADE
/
```

Comment: Since you have created the relevant JIRA, it will be processed by API manger team to future release

Comment: Thanks Marc. I think you can answer this question by mentioning the JIRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentoined in the question. The answer is adressed to WSO2 in a Jira issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2524).